# xCode TabBarItem title and icon color

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I can't seem to change the color of the Tabbaritem title and the icon when they're not highlighted. I want the color from the title and icon from grey to another color.

Comment: Search SO for "Tabbaritem" - there are lots of answers already there.

Answer (score 2):

> In AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
return YES;
}
```

> For Changing text color viewController.m

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
 self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self)
{
[self.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor greenColor],UITextAttributeTextColor,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS v5.0 provides methods to customize tabbaritem; read the documentation at this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html).